# Recursion in C++ program crashes

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to run a simple arithmetic recursion function in C++ using Visual Studio, but keep crashing the program. I did a trace of the function on paper and I believe it is accurate. Trying to compute the nth term of an arithmetic sequence given the parameters  a (starting value), b (constant difference), and n (value of nth term). Any ideas why my IDE crashes? New to programming, any help much appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 


int funSeq(int a, int b, int n);

void main(void)
{ 

    cout << funSeq(3, 2, 5) << endl; 

}



int funSeq(int a, int b, int n)
{
    if (n = 0)

        return a; 

    else
        return b + funSeq(a, b, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting. What is the error trace?

Comment: Typo: Use `if (n == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because in

```
if (n = 0)
```

you are **assigning** a value of `0` to `n` instead of **comparing** to it. The fix is (trivially) to change the operator:

```
if (n == 0)
```

Comment: That made it work- thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is setting function argument `n` to the value `0` by using the assignment operator `=`, instead you want to compare it to '0' with:

```
if (n == 0 )
```